# Change Hadoop MapReduce local resource visibility to PUBLIC

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, visibility, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to set the YARN visibility of a hadoop mapreduce local resource provided by the hadoop generic options -files or -archives.  Looking in yarn-site.xml I found where the files are written on a worker node using the -archives option, but based on other articles I've read and the directory it lands in (/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/myusername/appcache) that it's being treated as private.  I can't find any generic options or -D some.yarn.setting to change it from private to application or better yet, public.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "change from private to public"?

Comment: I poked around in the Hadoop source and found the string "mapreduce.job.cache.archives.visibilities" which can be set to a comma separated list (one for each -archives entry apparently), but setting that in the driver config doesn't seem to help.

Comment: If you look at [this Hortonworks link](http://hortonworks.com/blog/management-of-application-dependencies-in-yarn/) you'll see that it's possible to change local resource visibility of files and archives bundled with the map reduce job from private (default) to public and that public visibility will allow the files to persist between runs of the application.  Private resources will be deleted after every run of the application by the user.

Comment: I've tried adding -D mapreduce.job.cache.archives.visibilities=true,true on the command line and config.set("mapreduce.job.cache.archives.visibilities", "true,true") to no avail.  The 2 cached archives still appear in hadoop/yarn/usercache/username/filecache/<number> which I'm interpreting to mean it's still private visibility not public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the Hadoop code. These parameters (**mapreduce.job.cache.files.visibilities** and **mapreduce.job.cache.archives.visibilities**) cannot be set through configuration.

These parameters are defined in MRJobConfig.java:

```
  public static final String CACHE_FILE_VISIBILITIES = "mapreduce.job.cache.files.visibilities";

  public static final String CACHE_ARCHIVES_VISIBILITIES = "mapreduce.job.cache.archives.visibilities";
```

**org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.java**, has a function **uploadFiles()**. This function uploads the temporary files, jars and archives to the distributed cache:

This function determines the visibility of files and archives, by calling following function:

```
// set the public/private visibility of the archives and files
ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(conf);
```

The above mentioned function call, finally hits **determineCacheVisibilities()** function in **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.java**

As per the description of this function:

```
/**
   * Determines the visibilities of the distributed cache files and 
   * archives. The visibility of a cache path is "public" if the leaf component
   * has READ permissions for others, and the parent subdirs have 
   * EXECUTE permissions for others
   * @param job
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static void determineCacheVisibilities(Configuration job,
```

So the visibilities are determined based on the permissions of the leaf file and parent directories.

In **ClientDistributedCacheManager.java**, **isPublic()** method has the logic to calculate the visibilities:

```
//the leaf level file should be readable by others
if (!checkPermissionOfOther(fs, current, FsAction.READ, statCache)) {
  return false;
}
return ancestorsHaveExecutePermissions(fs, current.getParent(), statCache);
```

Finally, after determining the permissions, the visibilities are set in the following functions:

```
  static void setArchiveVisibilities(Configuration conf, String booleans) {
    conf.set(MRJobConfig.CACHE_ARCHIVES_VISIBILITIES, booleans);
  }

  static void setFileVisibilities(Configuration conf, String booleans) {
    conf.set(MRJobConfig.CACHE_FILE_VISIBILITIES, booleans);
  }
```

So, even if you specify these configurations in the command line, the configuration parameter is not considered. These configurations are set programmatically by the framework itself.

Also, I checked mapred-default.xml. There are no default configuration parameters for visibilities.

Comment: You rock.  I found the 2 constants after I posted, but didn't see any obvious direction to go investigating beyond that.   Interestingly, the Hortonworks link in my comments above vaguely alluded to the permissions on the files, but didn't spell anything out like you've done.  Well done!